# How can I use UserDefaults in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

How can I use UserDefaults to save/retrieve strings, booleans and other data in Swift?

Comment: I am reopening this question because it can server as a good general question on this topic. The accepted answer is also more clear than the [previous marked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25420651/store-string-in-nsuserdefaults), which was also more specific than this question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53587688/6630644

Comment: I think this question is available in stack overflow you should search before add question here

Comment: For easiest explanation Check this out : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lMIx7H4u4lg

Answer (score 422, accepted):

ref: [NSUserdefault objectTypes](http://www.codingexplorer.com/nsuserdefaults-a-swift-introduction/)

## Swift 3 and above

**Store**

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "Key") //Bool
UserDefaults.standard.set(1, forKey: "Key")  //Integer
UserDefaults.standard.set("TEST", forKey: "Key") //setObject
```

**Retrieve**

```
 UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "Key")
 UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Key")
 UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Key")
```

**Remove**

```
 UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "Key")
```

**Remove all Keys**

```
 if let appDomain = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier {
UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: appDomain)
 }
```

## Swift 2 and below

**Store**

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(newValue, forKey: "yourkey")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

**Retrieve**

```
  var returnValue: [NSString]? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("yourkey") as? [NSString]
```

**Remove**

```
 NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey("yourkey")
```

---

**Register**

> registerDefaults: adds the registrationDictionary to the last item in every search list. This means that after NSUserDefaults has looked for a value in every other valid location, it will look in registered defaults, making them useful as a "fallback" value. Registered defaults are never stored between runs of an application, and are visible only to the application that registers them.
>
> Default values from Defaults Configuration Files will automatically be registered.

for example detect the app from launch , create the struct for save launch

```
struct DetectLaunch {
static let keyforLaunch = "validateFirstlunch"
static var isFirst: Bool {
    get {
        return UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: keyforLaunch)
    }
    set {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: keyforLaunch)
    }
}
}
```

Register default values on app launch:

```
UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: [
        DetectLaunch.isFirst: true
    ])
```

remove the value on app termination:

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    DetectLaunch.isFirst = false

}
```

and check the condition as

```
if DetectLaunch.isFirst {
  // app launched from first
}
```

---

## UserDefaults suite name

another one property [suite name](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1409957-init), mostly its used for  [**App Groups concept**](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/shared-user-defaults-in-ios-3f15cd2c9409), the example scenario I taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50712737/separation-of-userdefaults-by-an-identifier-in-swift) :

> The use case is that I want to separate my UserDefaults (different business logic may require Userdefaults to be grouped separately) by an identifier just like Android's SharedPreferences. For example, when a user in my app clicks on logout button, I would want to clear his account related defaults but not location of the the device.

```
let user = UserDefaults(suiteName:"User")
```

[**use of userDefaults synchronize**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647931/nsuserdefaults-synchronize-method), the detail info has added in the duplicate answer.

Comment: When and where should you call the store methods? Just before the app closes or every time the values change?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik how will you update the value for a key in userdefaults?

Comment: @RajeshBaidya - userdefault always store  the final value only

Comment: Does this data persist through app installation/uninstallation?

Answer (score 55):

Best way to use **UserDefaults**

**Steps**

1. Create extension of UserDefaults
2. Create enum with required Keys to
   store in local
3. Store and retrieve the local data wherever you want

**Sample**

```
extension UserDefaults{

    //MARK: Check Login
    func setLoggedIn(value: Bool) {
        set(value, forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.isLoggedIn.rawValue)
        //synchronize()
    }

    func isLoggedIn()-> Bool {
        return bool(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.isLoggedIn.rawValue)
    }

    //MARK: Save User Data
    func setUserID(value: Int){
        set(value, forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.userID.rawValue)
        //synchronize()
    }

    //MARK: Retrieve User Data
    func getUserID() -> Int{
        return integer(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.userID.rawValue)
    }
}
```

**enum** for Keys used to store data

```
enum UserDefaultsKeys : String {
    case isLoggedIn
    case userID
}
```

**Save in UserDefaults** where you want

```
UserDefaults.standard.setLoggedIn(value: true)          // String
UserDefaults.standard.setUserID(value: result.User.id!) // String
```

**Retrieve data** anywhere in app

```
print("ID : \(UserDefaults.standard.getUserID())")
UserDefaults.standard.getUserID()
```

**Remove Values**

```
UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.userID)
```

This way you can store primitive data in best

**Update**
You need no use synchronize() to store the values. As @Moritz pointed out the it unnecessary and given the article about it.Check comments for more detail

Comment: You don't need `synchronize()`, it's explained in the documentation. It's not only useless here but could slow down the defaults access.

Comment: Yes it's mentioned in doc. Once the default data is changed it will save automatically but in some cases your values might not store i.e asynchronous. So i thought its better to sync.

Comment: It's not better - it's even the source of issues sometimes. Do not use sync, it's obsolete and problematic. See http://www.codingexplorer.com/nsuserdefaults-a-swift-introduction/ notably the "update" part. I also ran many tests about this and removed all calls to sync in all my apps and never had an issue even in dire situations. But hey, if you like useless stuff that can slow down your app, call sync... sure... ;)

Comment: It's really helpful. I have commented sync(). Using sync() is based on needed.

Comment: hii how to save data in nsuserdefaults in a seperate file in swift

Comment: A much cleaner approach is to use computed properties instead of pairs of setter/getter methods.

Answer (score 16):

***Swift 4*** :

**Store**

```
    UserDefaults.standard.set(object/value, forKey: "key_name")
```

**Retrive**

```
    var returnValue: [datatype]? = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "key_name") as? [datatype]
```

**Remove**

```
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey:"key_name")
```

Comment: what do you mean by this line 'UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()'  as optional ?  @NikunjJoshi

Answer (score 6):

**UserDefault+Helper.swift**

```
import UIKit

private enum Defaults: String {
   case countryCode = "countryCode"
   case userloginId   = "userloginid"
}

final class UserDefaultHelper {

static var countryCode: String? {
    set{
        _set(value: newValue, key: .countryCode)
    } get {
        return _get(valueForKay: .countryCode) as? String ?? ""
    }
}

static var userloginId: String? {
    set{
        _set(value: newValue, key: .userloginId)
    } get {
        return _get(valueForKay: .userloginId) as? String ?? ""
    }
}

private static func _set(value: Any?, key: Defaults) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(value, forKey: key.rawValue)
}

private static func _get(valueForKay key: Defaults)-> Any? {
    return UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: key.rawValue)
}

static func deleteCountryCode() {
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: Defaults.countryCode.rawValue)
 }

static func deleteUserLoginId() {
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: Defaults.userloginId.rawValue)
 }
}
```

**Usage:**

**Save Value:**

```
UserDefaultHelper.userloginId = data["user_id"] as? String
```

**Fetch Value:**

```
let userloginid = UserDefaultHelper.userloginId
```

**Delete Value:**

```
UserDefaultHelper.deleteUserLoginId()
```

Comment: Do not use `value(forKey:)`. That's from `NSObject` and key-value coding. Use the proper API provided by `UserDefaults`. That's `object(forKey:)`.

Answer (score 3):

I would say [Anbu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31203348/1371853) perfectly fine but I had to add guard while fetching preferences to make my program doesn't fail

Here is the updated code snip in **Swift 5**

> Storing data in UserDefaults

```
@IBAction func savePreferenceData(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Storing data..")
        UserDefaults.standard.set("RDC", forKey: "UserName") //String
        UserDefaults.standard.set("TestPass", forKey: "Passowrd")  //String
        UserDefaults.standard.set(21, forKey: "Age")  //Integer

    }
```

> Fetching data from UserDefaults

```
    @IBAction func fetchPreferenceData(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Fetching data..")

        //added guard
        guard let uName = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "UserName") else { return }
        print("User Name is :"+uName)
        print(UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Age"))
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//Save
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("yourString", forKey: "YourStringKey")

//retrive
let yourStr : AnyObject? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("YourStringKey")
```

Comment: In Swift 3:                                                                                                      
let minutes = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "minutes") as! String

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NSUserDefaults` in swift this way,

```
@IBAction func writeButton(sender: UIButton)
{
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.setObject("defaultvalue", forKey: "userNameKey")

}

@IBAction func readButton(sender: UIButton)
{
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let name = defaults.stringForKey("userNameKey")
    println(name) //Prints defaultvalue in console
}
```

Comment: The first version of this post said to use the `synchronize()` command for `NSUserDefaults` to make sure your stuff is saved after doing a block of changes.  This might have been more necessary in iOS 7 and earlier, **but in iOS 8 and on, you should not call synchronize() in most situations.**

Check this for more Info: http://www.codingexplorer.com/nsuserdefaults-a-swift-introduction/

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5 and above:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

defaults.set(25, forKey: "Age")
let savedInteger = defaults.integer(forKey: "Age")

defaults.set(true, forKey: "UseFaceID")
let savedBoolean = defaults.bool(forKey: "UseFaceID")

defaults.set(CGFloat.pi, forKey: "Pi")
defaults.set("Your Name", forKey: "Name")
defaults.set(Date(), forKey: "LastRun")


let array = ["Hello", "World"]
defaults.set(array, forKey: "SavedArray")


let savedArray = defaults.object(forKey: "SavedArray") as? [String] ?? [String()

let dict = ["Name": "Your", "Country": "YourCountry"]
defaults.set(dict, forKey: "SavedDict")

let savedDictionary = defaults.object(forKey: "SavedDictionary") as? [String: String] ?? [String: String]()
```

:)

Comment: you must end closure of "savedArray "

Answer (score 1):

I saved NSDictionary normally and able to get it correctly.

```
 dictForaddress = placemark.addressDictionary! as NSDictionary
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        userDefaults.set(dictForaddress, forKey:Constants.kAddressOfUser)
```

// For getting data from NSDictionary.

```
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let dictAddress = userDefaults.object(forKey: Constants.kAddressOfUser) as! NSDictionary
```

Comment: Thanks for your help miss. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
class UserDefaults_FavoriteQuote {
    static let key = "appname.favoriteQuote"

    static var value: String? {
        get {
            return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: key)
        }
        set {
            if newValue != nil {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: key)
            } else {
                UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: key)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I have Created my Custom Functions for Store Data in Userdefualts**

```
 //******************* REMOVE NSUSER DEFAULT *******************
 func removeUserDefault(key:String) {
  UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: key)
 }

 //******************* SAVE STRING IN USER DEFAULT *******************
 func saveInDefault(value:Any,key:String) {
  UserDefaults.standard.setValue(value, forKey: key)
 }


//******************* FETCH STRING FROM USER DEFAULT *******************
func fetchString(key:String)->AnyObject {
if (UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) != nil) {
    return UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: key)! as AnyObject;
}
 else {
    return "" as AnyObject
}
 }
```

Comment: Do not use `value(forKey:)` or `setValue`. That's from `NSObject` and key-value coding. Use the proper API provided by `UserDefaults`. That's `object(forKey:)` and `set`. Don't use `synchronize()`. It's documented as deprecated. And in Swift you don't need the `;` at the end of lines or the `( )` on `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most important things, in my mind, when creating UserDefaults is to make them easy for me to use, re-use and also easy for others to use.
Therefore I always make a UserDefaults key class that holdes the keys for my UserDefaults - thereby I am sure none can spell the key wrong.
I also make a Util class with the UserDefaults functions for saving and fetching the stored values.

Let me show you:

```
struct UserDefaultKeys {
    static let stringKey = "string-key"
}
```

And you use the key helper like this:

```
UserDefaultKeys.stringKey
```

Now to the helper class:

```
final class UserDefaultHelper {

    static let standard = UserDefaultHelper()

    func setString(stringToSave: String) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(userName, forKey: UserDefaultKeys.userKey)
    }

    func getString() -> String? {
        return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: UserDefaultKeys.userKey)
    }
}
```

And you use the helper class like this:

```
UserDefaultHelper.standard.setUserName(userName: "John")
```

Comment: There is no `setUserName(userName:)` method on your `UserDefaultHelper` class. Why create a `UserDefaultHelper` class? Why not create an extension on `UserDefaults` to add a property named `userName`. Implement the `get` and `set` to call the standard `set` and `string` methods. And if you do that, there's no need to create public keys since no one else will need to know the keys.

Answer (score -1):

In class `A`, set value for key:

```
let text = "hai"  
UserDefaults.standard.setValue(text, forKey: "textValue")
```

In class `B`, get the value for the text using the key which declared in class `A` and assign it to respective variable which you need:

```
var valueOfText  = UserDefaults.value(forKey: "textValue")
```

Comment: Do not use `value(forKey:)` or `setValue`. That's from `NSObject` and key-value coding. Use the proper API provided by `UserDefaults`. That's `object(forKey:)` and `set`.

Answer (score -1):

Swift 4,
I have used Enum for handling UserDefaults.

This is just a sample code. You can customize it as per your requirements.

For Storing, Retrieving, Removing.
In this way just add a key for your UserDefaults key to the enum.
Handle values while getting and storing according to dataType and your requirements.

```
enum UserDefaultsConstant : String {
    case AuthToken, FcmToken

    static let defaults = UserDefaults.standard


   //Store
    func setValue(value : Any) {
        switch self {
        case .AuthToken,.FcmToken:
            if let _ = value as? String {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(value, forKey: self.rawValue)
            }
            break
        }

        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }

   //Retrieve
    func getValue() -> Any? {
        switch self {
        case .AuthToken:
            if(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: UserDefaultsConstant.AuthToken.rawValue) != nil) {

                return "Bearer "+(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: UserDefaultsConstant.AuthToken.rawValue) as! String)
            }
            else {
                return ""
            }

        case .FcmToken:

            if(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: UserDefaultsConstant.FcmToken.rawValue) != nil) {
                print(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: UserDefaultsConstant.FcmToken.rawValue))
                return (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: UserDefaultsConstant.FcmToken.rawValue) as! String)
            }
            else {
                return ""
            }
        }
    }

    //Remove
    func removeValue() {
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: self.rawValue)
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
}
```

For storing a value in userdefaults,

```
if let authToken = resp.data?.token {
     UserDefaultsConstant.AuthToken.setValue(value: authToken)
    }
```

For retrieving a value from userdefaults,

```
//As AuthToken value is a string
    (UserDefaultsConstant.AuthToken.getValue() as! String)
```

Comment: Do not use `value(forKey:)` or `setValue`. That's from `NSObject` and key-value coding. Use the proper API provided by `UserDefaults`. That's `object(forKey:)` and `set`.

Answer (score -1):

use UserDefault to store any settings value you want your application to remember between start ups, maybe you want to know ifs its been started before, maybe you want some values the user has set to be remembers so they don't have to be set very time, on Mac windows frames are stored in there for you, maybe you want to control the behaviour of the app, but you don't want it available to end users, you just want to choose just before your release. Be careful what you store in UserDefaults, it's not protected.

Answer (score -1):

```
import Foundation

enum KeyName: String {
  case associatedUserName = "associatedUserName"
}

class UserDefaultsManager {

let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

static let shared = UserDefaultsManager()
private init(){ }

/// Get Value for the Key Name
///
/// - Parameter key: Name of the Name which is of type KeyName
/// - Returns: Value of T type
fileprivate func getObject<T>(key:String) -> T? {
    if let value = defaults.value(forKey: key), let castedValue = value as? T {
        return castedValue
    }
    return nil
}

/// State Object to UserDeafults Key-Value pair against their Key Name
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - key: Key Name as String
///   - value: Value for the Key
fileprivate func setObject<T>(key:String, value:T) {
    defaults.set(value, forKey: key)
 }
}

extension UserDefaultsManager {
// AssociatedUserName
var hasAssociatedUserName: String {
    get {
        if let state: String = self.getObject(key: KeyName.associatedUserName.rawValue) {
            return state
        }
        return EMPTY_STRING
    }
    
    set {
        setObject(key: KeyName.associatedUserName.rawValue, value: newValue)
    }
}
}
```

/**
Usage:

//SET

UserDefaultsManager.shared.hasBeenAssociatedWithBeacon = "Brahma"

//GET

print(UserDefaultsManager.shared.hasBeenAssociatedWithBeacon)

*/