# get information from struct in swift file

Tags: arrays, json, swift, class

so i have a class swift file that has a UserAccount class like this

```
class UserAccount{

 var userName: String!
 var email: String!
 var instaGram: String!
 var timeCreated: String!
 var like: String!
 var role: String!
 var active: String!
 var id: String!


init(userName: String, email: String, instaGram: String, timeCreated: String, like: String, role: String, active: String, id: String){

    self.userName = userName
    self.email = email
    self.instaGram  = instaGram
    self.timeCreated = timeCreated
    self.like = like
    self.role = role
    self.active = active
    self.id = id

 }
```

}

i have login view controller where i get the class variables and do my json and assign their values like this :

```
var userAcount = [UserAccount]() // Array Of Object
var user = UserAccount(userName: "", email: "", instaGram: "", timeCreated: "", like: "", role: "", active: "", id: "") //Init of Object
```

This is where i get my Json and add its value to its corresponding user class varible, i do this on my login view controller:

```
self.user.userName = userData.value(forKey: "userName") as! String
self.user.email = userData.value(forKey: "email") as! String
self.user.instaGram = userData.value(forKey: "instaGram") as! String
self.user.timeCreated = userData.value(forKey: "timeCreated") as! String
self.user.role = userData.value(forKey: "role") as! String
self.user.like = userData.value(forKey: "likes") as! String
self.user.id = userData.value(forKey: "id") as! String
self.user.active = userData.value(forKey: "active") as! String
```

this is where i append the information to my class array:

```
self.userAcount.append(self.user)
```

now my problem is that i dont know how to display the information in the UserAccount class on other view controllers, example the user profile view controller, is my first time working with users and profile, any help would be appreciated it, thank you

Comment: Why are all of your properties declared as implicitly unwrapped optionals? You should remove all of those `!` since you provide a non-optional value for everyone of them in the `init` method.

Comment: missed that, thank you @rmaddy

Comment: Provide more informations about what you want to do: "just display data", "Send data to other VC", "Show data in TableView" etc

Comment: @YerkebulanAbildin send data another VC

Answer (score 0):

To provide data to another `UIViewController`

1. Using `Storyboard` or `segue`

   ```
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
      if segue.identifier == "your_identifier", 
         let destinationVC = segue.destination as? YourViewController {
           destinationVC.userAcount = self.userAcount
       }
   }
   ```
2. Programmatically

   ```
   func gotoNextVC() {
       let destinationVC = YourViewController(nibName: "YourViewController", bundle: nil)
       destinationVC.userAcount = self.userAcount
       self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: true)

       // OR
       self.present(destinationVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In another ViewController make a Instance of your **UserAccount**.
When you wake that new view controller, pass value of **UserAccount**, to pass value you have two option 
**1. Storyborad/Segue**

```
func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
      if segue.identifier == "identifier"{ 
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as? YourViewController
        destinationVC.userAcount = self.userAcount
      }
   }
```

**2. By code**

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
   let controller = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:      identifier)
   controller.user = self.user
```

and now to access in your NewViewController you can simply access by

```
let userName = self.user.userName
```

Comment: this partially works, but if the user leaves the view and comes back to it, the variables loses its value, in other words, when the user first login and goes to his profile, it shows his email, but if he goes to another view and comes back to his profile view, then the email is nil @singh.jitendra

Comment: if this information don't have security concern than you can try **NSUserDefault** [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31203241/how-to-use-nsuserdefaults-in-swift)
It's easy to user but data is much private than you have to sore it local place like  coreData or in Sqlite @scs