# How To Make Onboarding/Intro Slides only Appear on Initial Login

Tags: swift

How can I make it so my intro onboarding instructions only appear when a user first logs into the application. Each time after, it will go straight to the regular login. Using Xcode 9, Swift 4 or previous.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please expand on the problem and provide an example of what you have tried. Please read the SO guidelines before posting.

Comment: Question doesn't follow SO guidelines as sparkplug mentioned but here's a video to get you started, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MQuzfjsQcHI

Comment: @sparkplug I have 3 ViewControllers that are a welcome onboarding intro (basically telling user 'hey welcome to the app, here's how it works') Then the initial vc with a basic signup/login. I want the onboarding vc's to only appear when a user First opens the app and scrolls through. Then every time after that the user is directed straight to the login/signup vc. Similar to the LinkedIn ios app where when it first open it explains instructions to a user then goes to the login. Wont appear any additional time as it detects the user has already gone over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a single Bool stored in UserDefaults. Check out this [post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31203241/how-to-use-userdefaults-in-swift)

Comment: thanks that helps a bit. I'm still just a little unsure how to apply a bool to if a user clicks a button to not show the screen again. As opposed to if they logged in

Comment: Please supply the code snippet you are working with. Is this an AlertView or UIButton? You need to set the boolean to true in the button action function. If the initial VC is the Onboarding VC, then in viewDidLoad() check if the boolean value is true. If it is, segue to your desired VC.

Comment: Hope this helps!