# Swift4 JSONDecoderExpected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead

Tags: php, json, swift

I'm pretty newbie with this, but I've been attempting to work out how JSONDecoder works for a login function that needs to retrieve data from a MySQL database, as shown in my code below and am receiving this error.

Swift Code:

```
func testParseJson(){

                var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://test.php")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        let postString = ("Email=test&Password=test")
        print(postString)
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                var responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
                print("new response string \(responseString)")
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let newData = try decoder.decode(User.self, from: data)
                print(newData.Email)
                print(newData.UserType)
            } catch let err {
                print("Err", err)
            }
            }.resume()
    }
```

Temporary Struct I have been attempting to use:

```
struct User: Decodable {
 let U_ID: String
 let Email: String
 let Password: String
 let UserType: String

private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case U_ID
    case Email
    case Password
    case UserType
 }
}
```

And the JSON response string reads:

```
[{"U_ID":"1",
"Email":"test",
"Password":"test",
"UserType":"Teacher"}]
```

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Here, JSON data is `Array` of `Objects`.

change

```
try decoder.decode(User.self, from: data)
```

to

```
try decoder.decode(Array<User>.self, from: data)
```

**Example:**

```
var users = [User]()

let data = """
[{"U_ID":"1","Email":"test","Password":"test","UserType":"Teacher"}]
""".data(using: .utf8)

do{
    users = try JSONDecoder().decode(Array<User>.self, from: data!)
}catch{
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}

print(users.first?.Email)
```

**Note:** For better understanding, this is my [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WxT1bKZ1HyQ&list=PLT7YNwQNKSPDgymAvqhbphhYxJHWeYsX6) series about JSON parsing in swift 4

Comment: That worked brilliantly.

As another noob question as I'm very new to swift, how might I access the users.first?.Email from somewhere else within the application?

Its a login but it will need to use the email again later on.

Thanks very much

Comment: You can use `UserDefaults` to save this kinda data. So, you can get it anywhere and anytime until the app uninstall or Offload or until the value delete(logout).

Comment: @ABowlofFruit, see here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31203241/how-to-use-userdefaults-in-swift/31203348

Comment: perfect answer. Thank you @RajamohanS

Comment: @amp.dev, You are welcome :D

Comment: also works if you replace `Array<User>.self` with `[User].self` which is a little more idiomatic.