# How to struct JSON array in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, struct

I want to struct my JSON array in Swift so I can use it, but everything I try throws an error. This is the JSON I'm working with:

```
[
      {
      "id": 15438,
      "date": "2019-05-07T03:36:51",
      "date_gmt": "2019-05-07T00:36:51",
      "type": "post",
      "title": {
      "rendered": "Title Here"
      }
    }
 ]
```

And this is the code I'm using:

```
struct getTitle: Decodable {
  let title: [Title]
}

struct Title: Decodable {
  let rendered: String?
}

class ViewController: NSViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let jsonUrlString = "URL HERE"
    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in

        guard let data = data else { return }

        do {
            let titleresult = try JSONDecoder().decode(getTitle.self, from: data)
            print(titleresult)

        } catch let jsonErr {
            print("Error serializing json:", jsonErr)
        }
      }.resume()
    }
  }
```

The error it's throwing is:

```
Error serializing json: typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, 
Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: 
"Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array 
instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

I already tried using

```
JSONDecoder().decode([getTitle].self, from: data)
```

to make it an array, but that throws the same error but turned around. It expected an array but found a dictionary.

I'm not sure what the problem is here. I already tried following multiple guides but they all result in the same thing. It's probably something with the struct I'm doing wrong but I don't know what.

Comment: `let title: [Title]` — `title` is not an array in your JSON

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift4 JSONDecoderExpected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49720958/swift4-jsondecoderexpected-to-decode-dictionarystring-any-but-found-an-array)

Comment: You are reading the error message backwards, the decoder expects a dictionary but you're giving it an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the error messages carefully and entirely, they are extremely descriptive.

> Expected to decode Dictionary but found an array instead

means the found object is an array. So the fix

```
JSONDecoder().decode([getTitle].self, from: data)
```

is basically right. But the subsequent error is quite different

> ...codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "title", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead."

Please notice the **codingPath**, it can be read like a key path `[0].title`: The value for key `title` in the first item of the root array is **not** an array, so change the struct to

```
struct getTitle: Decodable {
    let title: Title
}
```

Reading JSON is very easy: `{}` is dictionary which becomes a struct, `[]` is array.

Finally please name structs with starting capital letter.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I didn't look good enough at your previous answer. This was the solution indeed.

Comment: @Roan the solutions is given 18 mins before this answer , this is a stupid mistake of you not ones who gave correct answers before

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
struct getTitle: Decodable {
  let title: Title
}

struct Title: Decodable {
  let rendered: String?
}

class ViewController: NSViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let jsonUrlString = "URL HERE"
    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in

        guard let data = data else { return }

        do {
            let titleresult = try JSONDecoder().decode([getTitle].self, from: data)
            print(titleresult)

        } catch let jsonErr {
            print("Error serializing json:", jsonErr)
        }
      }.resume()
    }
  }
```

Comment: I already tried putting getTitle in brackets but that just reverses the error. It expects an array, finds a dictionary.

Comment: Look carefully also at getTitle struct

Answer (score 0):

You have a root array with `title` is a dictionary not array

```
struct getTitle: Codable { 
    let title: Title 
}

struct Title: Codable {
    let rendered: String
}
```

---

```
let titleresult = try JSONDecoder().decode([getTitle].self, from: data)
```

Comment: You're just changing the name and putting it in brackets right? That doesn't change the behavior of the code except it reverses the error. When in brackets it expects an array but finds a dictionary.

Comment: title is a dictionary with `{}` and top root is an array with `[]`

Comment: Copy the answer as it is the name doesn't matter , but you should start struct names with capital letter