# Clearing a subset of UserDefaults in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, userdefaults

The use case is that I want to separate my UserDefaults (different business logic may require Userdefaults to be grouped separately) by an identifier just like Android's SharedPreferences. For example, when a user in my app clicks on logout button, I would want to clear his account related defaults but not location of the the device saved in UserDefaults.

Comment: What’s so unclear about this question? I edited it, had got an answer much before editing that I accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [Suite name](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1409957-init)

`let user = UserDefaults(suiteName:"User")`

`let location = UserDefaults(suiteName:"Location")`