# What is the most common way to handle string names for Notifications and UserDefaults key names

Tags: swift, encapsulation

I will be using a few string names throughout my app for my Notifications and UserDefault names.

I have heard that for type safety it's a good practice to define your `notification` names or `UserDefaults` key names as static strings and make them part of a class or struct.

What is the most common way to handle string names for your Notification and UserDefault names?

I have thought about putting them in my AppDelgate class as global variables as follow...

```
let MY_STRING_NAME = "My string name"

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {}

/// Then just use MY_STRING_NAME in other classes.
```

Or

```
class SomeClass {
    let myStringName:String = "My string name"
}
/// Then use myClassInstance.myStringName
```

What is the best approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option for UserDefaults is to create a helper class that hides the fact that you are using UserDefaults. This makes it appear to the rest of your code just like you are using a simple class and its properties.

Something like this:

```
class MyAppPreferences {
    static let shared = MyAppPreferences()

    private let highScoreKey = "highScore"
    var highScore: Int {
        get {
            return UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: highScoreKey)
        }
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: highScoreKey)
        }
    }
}
```

On other code you can do this to set it:

```
MyAppPreferences.shared.highScore = 100
```

or the following to read it:

```
let score = MyAppPreferences.shared.highScore
```

Add a computed property and private key for each app preference needed in your app. This makes the rest of your code much cleaner.

And in for some reason you need to change how one or more of the preferences are stored in the future, you only need to change the code in one place.

For notification names, you can add constants to each class the notification is associated with. You see this pattern in many iOS classes such as UIApplication, UITextView, and others.

```
class SomeClass {
    static someClassEventNotification = NSNotification.Name("someUniqueName")
}
```

Comment: Wow, I really like your suggestion about UserDefaults, I love it.

Comment: I’m not exactly sure how would I use your approach for managing notification names if for instance I want to sand a notification from the AppDelegate/applicationWillEnterForeground class to my main View Controller class. Would you mind elaborating a little bit more?

Comment: You wouldn't use your own notification for that nor would you do anything in the app delegate. Simply have the view controller register for the existing `UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification` notification.

Comment: the op needs to know best way to create keys not to create the way data is stored

Comment: in this answer the op question is related to how to manage this `private let highScoreKey = "highScore"` not how to save

Comment: @rmaddy - Oh I see, thanks a lot for opening my eyes.

Comment: @Sh_Khan Yes, and I showed a good way to store keys for UserDefaults - by putting them as statics in a class. I added additional information to make it even more useful.

Answer (score 1):

The common approach is creating

```
struct Constants { 
   static let key1 = "value1"
   static let key2 = "value2"
   .....
}
```

// for notifications

```
extension Notification.Name {
  static let didReceiveData = Notification.Name("didReceiveData")
  static let didCompleteTask = Notification.Name("didCompleteTask")
}
```

---

some guys prefer global variables with ( k letter prefix )

```
let kDomain = "value1"
```

dates to `#define` in Objective-C , but using Constants is a clean way to code readers

Comment: That’s a lot for the suggestions. Would you mind showing me how would you use the extension?

Comment: There seems to be a move "away" from `extension Notification.Name {` and instead, define them with context of their use, `UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification` for example

Comment: @MadProgrammer this applies for custom notification names not what you mentioned

Comment: @Sh_Khan Not sure what you mean, but the core API seems to be moving away from `Notification.Name` extensions and placing them with the class context where they are used, why wouldn't you follow the core API convention?

Comment: my answer didn't say that `willEnterForegroundNotification` will be used in the extension it's for custom notification key names accross the app

Comment: @Sh_Khan You are missing the point being made by @MadProgrammer. If you look at my answer as well as the notifications defined in many iOS classes such as UIApplication, notifications are not being declared as an extension to `Notification.Name`. Yes, that was done in some cases, but generally they are being declared as statics in the class that is going to actually post those custom notifications.

Answer (score 1):

I think using enum is more appropriate way to define constants

**User Defaults:**

```
class MyAppPreferences {
    static let shared = MyAppPreferences()

    private enum Key: String {
        case userName
        case email
    }

    var userName: String? {
        get {
            return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: Key.userName.rawValue)
        }
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: Key.userName.rawValue)
        }
    }
}
```

**Notification:**

```
enum AppNotification: String {
    case didReceivedData
    case didCompleteTask
}

extension Notification.Name {
    init(_ appNotification:AppNotification) {
        self.init(appNotification.rawValue)
    }
}

//Use:

func notify() {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(.init(name: .init(.didReceivedData)))
}
```